# Trying to get day of week from variable queried by maxid

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to get day of week from a variable that is found by maxid, but I only get this error:

> Trying to get property 'dayOfWeek' of non-object

Code:

```
$dailyLog = DailyLog::with(['todoList','user'])->find(\DB::table('daily_logs')->max('id'));
$weekday = $dailyLog->date->dayOfWeek; 
$yesterdaysLog = DailyLog::loadByDate(Carbon::now()->subMonth(1)->next($weekday));
```

I am trying to get the day of week from the first query and compare it to last months same day of week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `$dailyLog->date` is not a Carbon object most probably, hence the reason why you cannot call `dayOfWeek`.. make sure that the `date` returns a Carbon instance.

To do that in your `DailyLog` model add this :

```
protected $dates = ['date'];
```

This will make sure that the `date` is cast to Carbon. But also make sure that for some reason that field is not `null` also.

Comment: in my DailyLog model I have `protected $fillable = ['date'];` already

Comment: yup, that's for mass-assignment protection. You also need what I said above.